# Posting data to Salesforce from an Azure Function (Is there a connector?)

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-functions

I've been searching for some time now for a way to interact with our Salesforce org easily through Azure functions and have been coming up dry. I guess where I am confused is that through Azure Logic Apps I can pretty simply connect into Salesforce and post data through them and I assume on their backend they must have some sort of built in connector to Salesforce.

Is this a package somewhere that I can utilize in Azure functions? This would simplify so much of what we are trying to accomplish with some of our integrations.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in Salesforce binding for Azure Functions, but one option you do have is to invoke your Logic Apps workflow from Azure Functions with the relevant payload, which would allow you to leverage all the built in connectors they have.

Comment: I have thought about this previously as an option but the problem comes in that we would need so many different entry points that I would have to create an inordinate amount of logic apps to make it work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any fancy connector.

For most use cases, you can use the Salesforce REST API:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest.htm

You can use Postman to test this API and get code samples which could easily be adapted to your Function App:
https://www.postman.com/salesforce-developers/workspace/salesforce-developers/collection/12721794-67cb9baa-e0da-4986-957e-88d8734647e2?ctx=documentation

But be careful!
Salesforce limits your API calls and it is very easy to blow these limits.

The naïve approach would be to post one record at a time.  Instead, try to collect as many records as possible and post them all at once.

If Salesforce does not need the data immediately, you can build a cache that will store data somewhere else (e.g. a MongoDb) and then periodically forward the data to Salesforce after it has been allowed to accumulate to some threshold quantity and/or a certain amount of time has elapsed.